# Synchronizing zoom between multiple charts

Tags: highcharts, chart.js

I have 4 charts, on the type of values on the x axis is 'date' and measure values on the y axis. What is the simplest way to synchronize zoom on the x axis between the 4 charts, and please give me an example if it's possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/20/

$(function () {
var chartSummary = [];

```
$(chartSummary).each(function (i, el) {
    $(el.container).mouseleave(function () {
        for (i = 0; i < chartSummary.length; i++)
        chartSummary[i].tooltip.hide();
    })

});

function syncTooltip(container, p) {
    var i = 0,
        j = 0,
        data;
    for (; i < chartSummary.length; i++) {
        if (container.id != chartSummary[i].container.id) {
            data = chartSummary[i].series[0].data;
            for (; j < data.length; j++)
            if (data[j].x === p) chartSummary[i].tooltip.refresh([chartSummary[i].series[0].data[j]]);
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    chartSummary[0] = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',

            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function (event) {
                    var xMin = event.min;
                    var xMax = event.max;
                    var ex = chart2.xAxis[0].getExtremes();


                    if (ex.min != xMin || ex.max != xMax) chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'mesure 1'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function () {
                            syncTooltip(this.series.chart.container, this.x);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [1356998400000, 151],
                [1359676800000, 52],
                [1362096000000, 10],
                [1364774400000, 56],
                [1367366400000, 45],
                [1370044800000, 11],
                [1372636800000, 52],
                [1375315200000, 54],
                [1377993600000, 32],
                [1380585600000, 76],
                [1383264000000, 87],
                [1385856000000, 54],
                [1388534400000, 65],
                [1391212800000, 22],
                [1393632000000, 71],
                [1396310400000, 25],
                [1398902400000, 65],
                [1401580800000, 42],
                [1404172800000, 84],
                [1406851200000, 46],
                [1412121600000, 10],
                [1414800000000, 2],
                [1417392000000, 90],
                [1420070400000, 63],
                [1422748800000, 74]
            ]
        }]
    });

    chartSummary[1] = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',

            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function (event) {
                    var xMin = event.min;
                    var xMax = event.max;

                    var ex = chart1.xAxis[0].getExtremes();

                    if (ex.min != xMin || ex.max != xMax) chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'mesure 2'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function () {
                            syncTooltip(this.series.chart.container, this.x);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [1356998400000, 151],
                [1359676800000, 52],
                [1362096000000, 10],
                [1364774400000, 56],
                [1367366400000, 45],
                [1370044800000, 11],
                [1372636800000, 52],
                [1375315200000, 54],
                [1377993600000, 32],
                [1380585600000, 76],
                [1383264000000, 87],
                [1385856000000, 54],
                [1388534400000, 65],
                [1391212800000, 22],
                [1393632000000, 71],
                [1396310400000, 25],
                [1398902400000, 65],
                [1401580800000, 42],
                [1404172800000, 84],
                [1406851200000, 46],
                [1412121600000, 10],
                [1414800000000, 2],
                [1417392000000, 90],
                [1420070400000, 63],
                [1422748800000, 74]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

I tried the above example.

Comment: In the above two charts, zoom is not getting synchronized.

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pr4d9fox/

Answer (score 0):

Here is working demo using [`afterSetExtremes`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) event and [`setExtremes`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis%23setExtremes#setExtremes) method

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)
```

```js
$.getJSON('//www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-c.json', function(data) {
  // Create the chart
  var chart1 = Highcharts.stockChart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container1',
      defaultSeriesType: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',

      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
          chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(event.min, event.max);
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: data,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });

  var chart2 = Highcharts.stockChart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container2',
      defaultSeriesType: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',

      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
          chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(event.min, event.max);
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: data,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container1" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

#### **https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/13fxg6cj/1/**

Comment: Here, I am not able to select a chart and zoom